# Connecting through Remmina to X11VNC Server

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, vnc

This puzzles me: I'm trying to connect through Remmina Remote Desktop Client to a X11vnc is a remote desktop server.

Both computers are running Linux, are online through a standard home DSL connection and have no fancy firewalls running.

Settings in Remmina:

[image]

When I connect the server laptop to the same dsl box as the client it connects without a problem.  If I try to connect over the internet - after adjusting the I.P. number I get "Unable to Connect to VNC Server".

How can I connect?

Details:

- VNC client - Remmina on Ubuntu 12.10.
- VNC server - x11vnc on Puppy Linux Wary

(see http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=27424 with x11vnc_server-0.9.4B.pet)

Comment: Did you configure port forwarding on your router? If you didn't, when you try to connect over the internet, the router dosen't know where to send the connection request.

Comment: @ScottGoodgame Oh no, I hoped this would be easier. So I have to physically go to the location where the "server" is and configure port forwarding on the router? (model: Alice DSL Modem WLAN 1421?)